# PyQt findChild() return None

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

These code return None. Why? How to fix it ?

add_GPU = add_menu.findChild(QAction, "actionGPU")
add_Machine = add_menu.findChild(QAction, "actionMachine")

Snippet from *.py

```
        add_menu = main_window.findChild(QMenu, "menuAdd")
        add_GPU = add_menu.findChild(QAction, "actionGPU")
        add_Machine = add_menu.findChild(QAction, "actionMachine")
        #Connect function to action
        add_GPU.triggered.connect(add_gpu)
        add_Machine.triggered.connect(add_machine)
```

Snippet from *.ui

```
<widget class="QMenu" name="menuAdd">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Add</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionGPU"/>
    <addaction name="actionMachine"/>
   </widget>
```

Comment: All menus and actions created in Designer are direct children of the main window, so you need to find `actionGPU` within `main_window`: the menu structure does not affect the action hierarchy, since actions (and menus) can be used in multiple places. In any case, all this is completely unnecessary, since both the `uic` module and the pyuic generated classes already create attributes for them, so `add_menu` is already available as `main_window.menuAdd`, `add_GPU is `main_window.actionGPU` and so on.

Comment: @musicamante I still don't get what you meant. I don't use pyuic to generate *.py
Do you know what's missing in findChild() ?

Comment: There are 2 ways of using Designer files: with the `uic` module functions, or by "building" them with the `pyuic` command-line tool as python scripts that act in a similar way (see the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)). In either case, you generally do **not** need to use `findChild()` at all, as all objects are available to the UI instance just by using their object name set in Designer. If you're using the uic module and are "building" the `main_window` from it, all those objects are accessible as attributes of »

Comment: »  `main_window`  just from their object name. If in Designer you have an object named "whatever", then you can directly get it by accessing `main_window.whatever`. The only "acceptable" reason for using `findChild()` is to allow some level of auto completion (unless the IDE is properly set up with appropriate plugins) which would otherwise be unavailable in normal conditions, due to the way objects are dynamically created.